# How to prevent onActivityCreated to be called in dialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I am using a dialog fragment CDialogFragment in my app.
I need to dismiss my DialogFragment on Activity recreation.
To handle I used dismiss() method as -

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogSlideAnim2);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
      dismiss();
    }
  }
```

Its is working fine, On Activity recreation my dialog fragment dismissed.

Problem is that after calling dismiss in onCreate(), onActivityCreated() is being called.

To stop onActivityCreated(), I used code in onCreate() as -

```
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
     dismiss(); 
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
    }
```

But not able to stop onActivityCreated()

I also used onDetached() but no solution

Please give a solution

Comment: "I need to dismiss my DialogFragment on Activity recreation" -- that makes little sense. You are saying that if the user rotates the screen, or you otherwise undergo a configuration change, that you want the dialog to disappear. That is odd, but if it is truly what you want, stop using `DialogFragment`. The **complete and entire *point*** of `DialogFragment` is to retain and re-display the dialog after a configuration change.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, destroy it a lot earlier: no need to recreate it when you don't want to show it again.

1. When you show/create your dialog, save it in a global parameter in your Activity: Dialog dialog.
2. onStop of your activity, dismiss it so that it won't come back in your new creation: dialog.dismiss();

Comment: ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState if I dismiss() dialog in onStop()

Comment: then call it in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) maybe, before calling the super. that method is always called if the system thinks it might restore the instance in the future.